# @OneToMany relationship between two tables each having composite Primary Keys

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Can someone please provide a working example of how to map with JPA/Hibernate a @OneToMany relationship between two tables each having compound primary keys as follows:

Is it needed to create a FK constraint when creating the Table B in Oracle for that purpose? How would it be?

[image]

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You need to isolate the compound key into an @Embeddable key. Here you can find a working example. [https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a class to compound multi fields.

```java
@Embeddable
public class CompoundKey implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "PK1", columnDefinition = "INT", nullable = false)
  private Long pk1;

  @Column(name = "PK2", columnDefinition = "INT", nullable = false)
  private Long pk2;
}
```

Then use it like:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableA")
public class A implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -1239386304051447322L;

  @EmbeddedId
  private CompoundKey pKey;

  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
  private List<B> bList;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableB")
public class B implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -589397418901916036L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
  private String id;

  @ManyToOne
  private A a;

  private LocalDateTime date;
}
```

At last the generated ddl should be:

```sql
Hibernate: drop table tablea if exists
Hibernate: drop table tableb if exists
Hibernate: drop sequence if exists hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
Hibernate: create table tablea (pk1 INT not null, pk2 INT not null, name varchar(255), primary key (pk1, pk2))
Hibernate: create table tableb (id varchar(255) not null, date timestamp, a_pk1 INT, a_pk2 INT, primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table tableb add constraint FKs0bksprwc7qy2dll3ihn795cr foreign key (a_pk1, a_pk2) references tablea
```

Well, I haven't run any CRUD test.
Just an advice: Be careful with `@OneToMany`, it could generate a 3rd table which reference to your two tables.